# Activities for High School ham radio club

Tags: diy

I just started an Amateur Radio Club at our High School (KE0FXH)

Our school is not a technical school (it is an arts school) and I am trying to find activities to get students interested in ham radio and technology.

So far, I ran a foxhunt, we built a mini repeater out of two old wideband 440 radios and a raspberry pi, and I plan on experimenting with packet for all of the kids who are interested in computers.

What other projects / activities make good ham radio clubs?

I am the only kid there in the 4-6 member club who has electronic experience, and I am thinking along the lines of basic electronics for ham radio. The budget is also very limited, its an entirely student funded club plus whatever donations we get.

Comment: Um, this question just invites “here's MY favorite activity”. Can you revise it into something that can actually have a single answer?